# Call function after oauth success

Tags: facebook, authentication, oauth-2.0

How can I call a function, when Facebook has been authourized??

```
FB.ui({
    client_id: '9999999999999',
    method: 'oauth',
    scope: 'email, user_about_me, user_likes',
    response_type: 'token'
});
```

???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FB.Ui has a [callback function](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/).

```
FB.ui(
  {
    method: 'feed',
    name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
    link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
    picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
    caption: 'Reference Documentation',
    description: 'Dialogs provide a simple, consistent interface for applications to interface with users.'
  },
  function(response) {
    if (response && response.post_id) {
      alert('Post was published.');
    } else {
      alert('Post was not published.');
    }
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Facebook state that you should not use the OAuth Dialog directly from the Javascript SDK so here's an example using FB.Login with a callback for when the user has accepted/denied the permissions.

```
FB.login(function(response) 
  {
      if (response.authResponse)
      {
          // user has granted permissions
      } 
      else
      {
          // user did not grant permissions
      }
  }, 
  {
      scope: 'email, user_about_me, user_likes'
  }
);
```